# How to organize my binder of activities for review of time as assistant professor?

Tags: evaluation, document-organization

I am up for review and I must compile a lot of materials from my time as an assistant professor.  Everything has to be submitted in hard copy in a binder.  I would like to make it as easy as possible for the committee to read.  I must submit the following:

1. A cover letter
2. A CV
3. List of all courses taught, along with syllabuses
4. My annual reports (about three pages per year)
5. Every student evaluation from every class taught
6. Lists of various activities that include scholarship, professional development, and service.

I thought I would organize it so that each of the categories above would get their own tab in the binder. Each of the categories in (6) will get their own tab as well. My main concern is the evaluations from (5). I teach three or four classes per semester.  So, I have dozens of classes with evaluations. If I only give a single tab to all the evaluations, it would be hard to navigate. And, each class getting its own tab seems excessive. Is there a way to have (1) through (6) have tabs that are easy to pick out, while still maintaining some kind of sub-tab system for each semester?  Or, is there a better way to organize all this stuff?  Thanks.

Comment: Use sticky notes to separate each class.

Comment: Why don't you try asking your chair if they have a preferred way to organize things?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you had the right idea about having six tabs to organize each section. From there, I would have card stock paper (or something similar) to separate out your evaluations by semester. Have each semester labeled on each sheet. That will create a subtle yet efficient way of dividing out your evaluations.